# Using psycopg2 and BeautifulSoup to scrape images to postgres BLOB

Tags: python, postgresql, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a BeautifulSoup scraper to grab images directly from URLs and upload them to a postgres table.  When I run the below code in terminal, the prompt hangs as if it's doing something -- but no data ends up in the table.  (I know the URLs are correct.)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import datetime
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# INSERT THE DATA
def create_table():
    '''Create table in database.'''
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect('''
                                conn string
                                ''')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # Create table for database.
        cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists tablename (
                timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
                ,pic_col_1 bytea
                ,pic_col_2 bytea
                ,pic_col_3 bytea
    )''')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

create_table()

def insert_data(timestamp, s1, s2, s3):
    '''Insert data into the database.'''
    conn = psycopg2.connect('''
                            conn string
                            ''')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO tablename
                (timestamp, img1, img2, img3) 
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)''', (timestamp, s1, s2, s3))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


# Save data in a Postgresql database.
while True: 
    # GET THE DATA
    img1 = requests.get('http://website.com/files/apple.jpg')
    img2 = requests.get('http://website.com/files/banana.jpg')
    img3 = requests.get('http://website.com/files/cranberry.jpg')

    ximg1 = img1.extract()
    ximg2 = img2.extract()
    ximg3 = img3.extract()


    time_now = datetime.datetime.today()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.strftime(time_now, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    print(timestamp)
    insert_data(timestamp, ximg1, ximg2, ximg3)
```

Comment: What is `extract()` method here? `img1.extract()`

Comment: ah yeah that part is clearly wrong... `PageElement.extract() removes a tag or string from the tree. It returns the tag or string that was extracted:`

Comment: Can you show whole code? requests.get() returns `Response` object not `PageElement`

Comment: that is the whole code -- with just the URLs and connection strings obscured